# Ubuntu asking for password again and again

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, mate

Ubuntu asking for password again and again
I am also having the same problem . When I enter my password while booting up, it shows screen with system loadings for a split second and takes me back to password entry screen

Comment: My problem was that the hard drive was full 100%

Comment: I've solve this issue by following way : Check here... https://askubuntu.com/a/1318368/1185282

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+f1 then once you log in to command line try to create a file or folder to see if the problem is not lack of disk space.

Comment: @Bahax how did you resolve the issue if the HDD was full?

Comment: @ankushjamthikar, sorry I don't remember this issue at all, but from the top of my head maybe you can use a live CD or USB to delete some stuff?

Answer (score 5):

When the password entry screen appears on the display manager screen
press `Ctrl + Alt + F1`. After that, you will get to the console. There enter
login and then password.

```
sudo chmod -R u+w /home/user
cd /home/user
sudo rm -f .Xauthority .ICEauthority
```

go through live USB, when you start clicked to restore the system - it also helps

Comment: thanks, man! I've moved both .Xauthority and .ICEauthority to backup, and worked like a charm.

Comment: didn't worked for me

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + Alt + F1` did not work in my case of Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> did take me to the command line.

My issues did not end there however, I simply could not issue any command (resulted in error "Command ... not included in the PATH environment variable") until `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`.
But then, to my dismay, none of the procedures listed here helped.
What worked is the answer by Prometheus and Chaos at https://askubuntu.com/questions/249363/my-ubuntu-system-is-asking-login-again-and-again-when-i-even-entered-the-correct

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 19.10 and changing the PATH variable in /etc/environment caused asking the password again and again when I wanted to restart my machine. I used another environment variable in my PATH variable and Ubuntu didn't like it.

So as Arthur wrote I pressed Ctrl + F2 when it asked the password, logged in, realized the problem with `echo $PATH`, edited the PATH variable with `nano /etc/environment`, replaced the other variable in the PATH with its value, restarted my machine, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my laptop and solved it by following below steps:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and It will open the console.
2. Enter your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Enter your username password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Run command: `mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak`
5. Run command: `exit`
6. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> for graphical mode.
7. Try to login by entering your password.

Comment: It is interesting to know why such a significant issue occurs

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit. My nvidia driver was the reason of it. I dont't know the details. However removing nvidia-340 package fixed the trouble (**apt-get remove nvidia-340**).